# Filtering in sql

Tags: sql

[image: Please see current and desired result below]

I believe I can get the desired set using a union below

```
select C, P, sum(A) from table where C in ('AU','IN') group by 1,2
Union
Select C,  sum(A) from table where C in ('JP') group by 1
```

But was wondering if there is an alternate/easy solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select C, P, A
from table
where C in ('AU','IN') 
Union ALL
select C,  NULL, sum(A)
from table
where C in ('JP')
group by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just say this:

```sql
select C,
       case C
         when 'JP' then 'total'
         else           C
       end as C
       sum(A) as A
from table
where C in ('AU', 'IN', 'JP')
group by C,
         case C
           when 'JP' then 'total'
           else C
         end
```

No expensive `union all`. Just a straightforward `select...group by`